# How to ask manager who just gave me an appraisal email, for a LinkedIn recommendation

Tags: references, linkedin, recommendation-letter

I work part time for a company. My manager is in another city. We recently completed a project and he sent me an appraisal email and a generous bonus that I really wasn't expecting. In fact I'm embarrassed.

What would help me the most is if I could get a recommendation from a manager on my LinkedIn profile. How should I ask him? Even just a copy/paste from the email would be sufficient.

Update: I asked two managers and they both have yet to accept my linkedin connection request.

Comment: What's wrong with using the built in LinkedIn tools to make the request?

Comment: @JoelEtherton didn't know there was such a thing

Comment: If you're connected on LinkedIn already you can request they add a recommendation for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ask him. You can ask in a 1-on-1 meeting when opportunity arises, or email/message him with a request.

Mention that if he would be willing to provide a recommendation, you will send him a request via LinkedIn, and will confirm when you've sent it so he knows it's waiting for him.

Some people don't monitor LinkedIn notifications and do not login frequently, so you want to make it as easy for him as possible. Good luck!

Comment: I agree that just asking him directly is the best option, definitely strike while the iron is hot. I would simply explain that you (the OP) are really proud of the work and believe having an appraisal on your LinkedIn from your manager would be beneficial for your career.

Comment: I was more asking what words to use?

Comment: @user130167 Between my response and the comment above should give you a good idea. That said, it is best if you write in your own words.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bright idea.  The whole point of LinkedIn recommendations is to present your suitability for *new* opportunities.  You're going to ruin a good situation with your boss by suggesting that he help your chances of working for somebody else.  If you're doing a great job at work, your boss would have to be pretty dumb to carry out what you're trying to do here, and purposely lose a good employee.

You might quietly ask other people that you work with, but as LinkedIn pages are public, your boss could retaliate against them *and* you.  This kind of thing is very sensitive.

Comment: Since it's part time I don't think he'd see it that way. But good point anyway.

Comment: That sounds like overanalyzing things quite a bit. Asking for a recommendation on LinkedIn does not necessarily mean the person is sitting on a packed suitcase ready to dash to the next job. It is rational to request a recommendation while the memory of an employee's performance is fresh in the manager's memory and isn't seen as water under the bridge. Given the part time nature of the work and the fact that building a solid LinkedIn profile is a process that takes time and patience, I would encourage to proceed, with the caveat to not force the issue if the manager happens to drag his feet.