# Is it bad to request a LinkedIn recommendation?

Tags: linkedin, recommendation-letter

I had asked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/179840/how-to-ask-manager-who-just-gave-me-an-appraisal-email-for-a-linkedin-recommend/179853#179853) and the most upvoted answer states it's bad to ask (or even receive) recommendation letters over LinkedIn, because it shows your current employer you're looking for new work (which is seen as a negative).

To me this seems a bit presumptuous. Recommendations are not that all uncommon on LinkedIn. When is it positive/negative to ask or receive one? With this view I guess it's safer to have a private recommendation letter so you can control who sees it?

Comment: Why are you so fixated on receiving Linkedln recommendations?  You don't need Linkedln for someone to give you a recommendation and you don't need your recommendations to be public.....

Comment: Also, calling the community "presumptuous" is probably not a good way to endear yourself here.

Comment: It seems reasonable for someone to ask about LinkedIn recommendations without being "fixated" on them

Comment: @PhilipKendall don't put words in my mouth please. I never said "community" I said an "answer" which advises against something that is common. I hope you can understand the difference.

Comment: Also the tech quiz is a good idea to showcase on your profile.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it bad to request a LinkedIn recommendation?

Not really bad but not useful either. No one cares about LinkedIn recommendations. Anyone can write anything so they have almost no credibility. Instead focus on having 2-3 really good references either in writing or (better) someone a potential hiring manager could reach out to.

Comment: I know there even exist groups where members exchange phony linkedin recommandations, even though they've never worked together. In the end, I pretty much agree with you that recruiters rarely care about those

Answer (score 1):

The point of that answer is that asking *your current employer* for a reference is a bad move.  Asking other people is fine.

LinkedIn is mainly used for job-hunting.  If you are actively soliciting references, then it strongly hints that you are looking for a new job.

Letting your employer know that you are looking for a new job will harm your prospects in the current one.  You are less likely to be promoted, and you are less likely to be put on important new work.  If you actually find the new job reasonably quickly, that doesn't matter.  But if you can't find that job, then you end up worse off than you were before.

Comment: Why would it be bad to ask for a reference? Isn't a reference is basically like, "Simon B is a great worker, we're really glad to have him." It's not saying you're finding new work per say. It depends on your relationship with your boss/employer I think more so than anything else.

Answer (score -1):

LinkedIn recommendations are good. While as a tech hiring manager I also want contacts I can reach out to for references, "private written" references are much like printed resumes - fine but somewhat old-timey. I'd rather use someone's LinkedIn in place of a resume if I can.  Those recommendations only hold as much weight as the person who gave them of course.

Timing of adding recommendations is like timing of updating your LinkedIn in general.  Some people will take it as a warning sign, others understand it's not. The best way for you to make it perceived as routine is to make it routine - I update my LI fairly regularly so it's not tied to job moves. Natural transition periods are good too (changing bosses, someone leaving the team, etc.) so it's more obviously "let's strike while the iron is hot" not a move towards leaving.